# Jupyter Lab real-time collaboration

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

So I am a physics student and I use Jupyter Lab for my Lab data analysis. Basically we work in groups of three students and we wanted to find a way to share our notebooks, so that everyone can collaborate into the code and make changes to it. We want to make it like we can see in real time the changes in the notebooks made by others, and not just sending each other the notebooks every time we make a slight change in the code.

I looked up on the internet, and found out that there is an extension called real-time collaboration that could be the one we were looking for, but I didn't really understand how it works. Some seems to say that if you share the link with this tool, you give access to all the file on the server and not just the notebook (and I don't want that). I also found Jupyter Hub and it says that it is used for lab team in data analysis, but it seems pretty difficult to start up and I don't know if it's worth for just a three people team.

Comment: By "all the files on the server" they mean all the files **hosted by the jupyter-server** which is likely what you do want. You just need to ensure to set root dir to whatever directory you want to share with others. The jupyter root directory defaults to the location from which you start jupyter lab in command line but can be adjusted.

Comment: So what I need to do is just start jupyter lab in the directory in which I want the others to see my file? Sometimes I start it from the home directory and then I go for the directory I want, but in that case it would take into account the home directory if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Ok, thank you !

Comment: Just adding to the previous comment, while only the files in jupyter root directory will be shared with collaborators, they potentially could access your other files via terminal or specific kernel if these are not sandboxed, so if you are not trusting your collaborators you should create a system user that only has access to one specific directory and use it to host the jupyter server.